# How to fix connection being refused from GKE when deployed a shiny app using docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine, shinydashboard

I am very new to cloud platform and docker and I am trying to run a shiny app on Google Kubernetes Engine however when I try to access my application I get the error `connection refused` on the webpage.

As per the article 
https://code.markedmondson.me/r-on-kubernetes-serverless-shiny-r-apis-and-scheduled-scripts/
I have created a docker image for my app, pushed it to the container registry and deployed on Kubernetes engine using the above article.

However I am not able to identify where am I going wrong. I followed the below article as well however could not fix the issue.

[Dockerizing shiny-app using a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266221/dockerizing-shiny-app-using-a-dockerfile)

Below is the docker file that I used to build my image.

```
FROM r-base:3.4.2

# install R package dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ##### ADD YOUR DEPENDENCIES
    ## clean up
    && apt-get clean \ 
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ \ 
    && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds

# Install dependencies of app
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown','dplyr','ggplot2','shinydashboard'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

# copy the app to the image
COPY app.R /srv/shiny-server/app.R

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

Below is the yml file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: r-ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: / 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /wordcloud/
      # app deployed to /wordcloud/
        backend:
          serviceName: shiny
          servicePort: 8080
```

Please can someone help to identifying where am I going wrong and please help to resolve this.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Can you paste deployment yaml in the question

Comment: @Veerendra, Thanks a lot for your response. I have updated the yml file in the question. would really appreciate your help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you deploy dummy pod like `curl` image and see you are able to access the service `shiny` from that pod.

Comment: @Veerendra Apologies for the late reply. I am not sure what you are suggesting. To be very honest I am very new to docker and Kubernetes. Is it possible to contact you offline if you dont mind.

Comment: Wrong config in Load Balancer service maybe?